# How to compile the Android runtime (ART) from source

Tags: java, android, git, android-ndk

I am trying to compile the Android runtime using the Android NDK. First I cloned the repository and switched to the `marshmallow-cts-release` branch. Then when running `ndk-build` I get

```sh
suici@HP-Pavilion-g7:~/art$ ndk-build
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-local.mk:151: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
suici@HP-Pavilion-g7:~/art$
```

How do I compile this ? Do I need the entire Android source tree ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

The repository contains the `Android.mk` file. I am using elementary OS freya 64-bit (based on Ubuntu) on a HP Pavilion g7-2269wm. Latest SDK and NDK are installed.

After freshly cloning the source for ART and compiling it by running the following.

```sh
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art
cd art
git checkout marshmallow-cts-release
export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$PWD
ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk
```

I get

```
build/Android.common_path.mk:20: art/build/Android.common.mk: No such file or directory
build/Android.oat.mk:24: art/build/Android.common_build.mk: No such file or directory
build/Android.oat.mk:143: warning: overriding commands for target `/core.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:143: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:143: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-pic.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:143: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-pic.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:144: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-optimizing.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:144: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-optimizing.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:144: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-optimizing-pic.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:144: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-optimizing-pic.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:145: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-interpreter.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:145: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-interpreter.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:145: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-interpreter-pic.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:145: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-interpreter-pic.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:149: warning: overriding commands for target `/corevalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:149: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/corevalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:149: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-picvalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:149: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-picvalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:150: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-optimizingvalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:150: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-optimizingvalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:150: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-optimizing-picvalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:150: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-optimizing-picvalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:151: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-interpretervalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:151: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-interpretervalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:151: warning: overriding commands for target `/core-interpreter-picvalgrind.art'
build/Android.oat.mk:151: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/core-interpreter-picvalgrind.art'
build/Android.cpplint.mk:17: art/build/Android.common_build.mk: No such file or directory
find: `art': No such file or directory
runtime/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.common_build.mk: No such file or directory
compiler/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.common_build.mk: No such file or directory
dex2oat/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.executable.mk: No such file or directory
disassembler/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.common_build.mk: No such file or directory
oatdump/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.executable.mk: No such file or directory
imgdiag/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.executable.mk: No such file or directory
patchoat/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.executable.mk: No such file or directory
dalvikvm/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.common.mk: No such file or directory
dalvikvm/Android.mk:42: /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/executable_prefer_symlink.mk: No such file or directory
dalvikvm/Android.mk:72: /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-host-executable.mk: No such file or directory
dalvikvm/Android.mk:75: /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/executable_prefer_symlink.mk: No such file or directory
tools/Android.mk:25: /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/base_rules.mk: No such file or directory
tools/Android.mk:35: /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/base_rules.mk: No such file or directory
tools/dexfuzz/Android.mk:33: /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/base_rules.mk: No such file or directory
sigchainlib/Android.mk:19: art/build/Android.common_build.mk: No such file or directory
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'sigchain' in sigchainlib/Android.mk.    
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by sigchainlib/Android.mk.    
/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

Output of `echo $NDK_PROJECT_PATH`

```
/home/suici/AndroidRuntime/art
```

Output of `ls $PWD`

```
Android.mk    cmdline   dex2oat       MODULE_LICENSE_APACHE2  patchoat     test
build         compiler  disassembler  NOTICE                  runtime      tools
CleanSpec.mk  dalvikvm  imgdiag       oatdump                 sigchainlib
```

Comment: Post the results for `echo NDK_PROJECT_PATH` and `ls ~/art`

Comment: @m0skit0 Added them to the answer

Comment: @m0skit0 I have fixed the problem but it needs to be run as 32-bit which is annoying and may be slow (don't know, but my Nexus 9 64-bit is fast because it uses 64-bit ART / Dalvik)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the ASOP source and built it for x86_64. In a folder I could find the `dalvikvm` binary which is what I wanted. But I have a problem with it.

First to install all the Android libraries I copied everything in `out/host/linux-x86/lib/` to `/usr/bin` and everthing in `out/host/linux-x86/lib64/` to `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and ran `ldconfig -v -n /usr/lib` and `ldconfig -v -n /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to get all the Android libs (64 and x86)

When executing `./dalvikvm` I get

```
art F  6066  6066 art/runtime/utils.cc:1218] ANDROID_ROOT not set and /system does not exist
art F 6066 6066 art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]Runtime aborting...
(Aborting thread was not attached to runtime!)
  native: #00 pc 000000000040de55  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+213)
  native:   art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/utils.cc:1102
  native: #01 pc 00000000003cb9b4  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+292)
  native:   art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/runtime.cc:308
  native: #02 pc 00000000003bea5f  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+127)
  native:   art::Dumpable<art::AbortState>::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/base/dumpable.h:38
  native:   std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& art::operator<< <art::AbortState>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Dumpable<art::AbortState> const&)
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/base/dumpable.h:49
  native:   art::Runtime::Abort()
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/runtime.cc:366
  native: #03 pc 000000000010ed1e  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1150)
  native:   ~LogMessage
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/base/logging.cc:226
  native: #04 pc 000000000040ec37  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::GetAndroidRoot()+231)
  native:   art::GetAndroidRoot()
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/utils.cc:1223
  native: #05 pc 000000000036906f  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::ParsedOptions::Parse(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool, art::RuntimeArgumentMap*)+4351)
  native:   art::ParsedOptions::Parse(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool, art::RuntimeArgumentMap*)
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/parsed_options.cc:534
  native: #06 pc 0000000000367edf  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::ParsedOptions::Create(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool, art::RuntimeArgumentMap*)+95)
  native:   art::ParsedOptions::Create(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool, art::RuntimeArgumentMap*)
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/parsed_options.cc:49
  native: #07 pc 00000000003bf2f8  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Init(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool)+136)
  native:   art::Runtime::Init(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool)
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/runtime.cc:791
  native: #08 pc 00000000003bf24b  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Create(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool)+75)
  native:   art::Runtime::Create(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void const*> > > const&, bool)
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/runtime.cc:417
  native: #09 pc 00000000002be339  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libart.so (JNI_CreateJavaVM+569)
  native:   JNI_CreateJavaVM
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:805
  native: #10 pc 0000000000001e1f  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/bin/dalvikvm64 (main+463)
  native:   art::dalvikvm(int, char**)
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/dalvikvm/dalvikvm.cc:177
  native:   main
  native:    /mnt/storage/AOSP/art/dalvikvm/dalvikvm.cc:212
  native: #11 pc 0000000000021ec4  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so (__libc_start_main+244)
  native:   __libc_start_main
  native:    /build/eglibc-3GlaMS/eglibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.c:287
  native: #12 pc 0000000000001b28  /mnt/storage/AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/bin/dalvikvm64 (???)

Aborted (core dumped)
```

When running `dalvikvm --32` everything seems to work correctly after modifying my `~/.bashrc` by adding the following lines to it.

```
export ANDROID_ROOT=!!!PATH-TO-AOSP!!!/out/debug/host/linux-x86/product/generic_x86_64/system

# configure bootclasspath
export BOOTCLASSPATH=$ANDROID_ROOT/framework/core.jar:$ANDROID_ROOT/framework/ext.jar:$ANDROID_ROOT/framework/framework.jar:$ANDROID_ROOT/framework/android.policy.jar:$ANDROID_ROOT/framework/services.jar

# this is where we create the dalvik-cache directory; make sure it exists
export ANDROID_DATA=/tmp/dalvik_$USER
```

Replace `!!!PATH-TO-AOSP!!!` with the path to your AOSP folder.Then running `mkdir -p $ANDROID_DATA/dalvik-cache` to create the folders.

Dalvik is working in 32-bit but not in 64-bit.This is a 64-bit computer running elementary OS freya